# Finagle client call jersey or other http server

Tags: java, finagle

I'm trying to call jersey http server running on `localhost:8080` (http/1.1) using finagle client in java with following code.

```
Service<HttpRequest, HttpResponse> client = ClientBuilder.safeBuild(ClientBuilder.get()
            .hosts("localhost:8080")
            .codec(Http.get())
            .retries(3)
            .hostConnectionLimit(5)
            );

    HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/");

    client.apply(request).addEventListener(new FutureEventListener<HttpResponse>() {
        public void onSuccess(HttpResponse response) {
            System.out.println("Response received: "+ response);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable cause) {
            System.out.println("Failed with cause: "+ cause);
        }
    });
```

But response is coming:-

> Response received: DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
>   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Although it is working perfectly with finagle server.
I`m not getting why it is not working. Though finagle is protocol agnostic. 
Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replacing "/" with a valid url like localhost:8080/jersey/hello, working perfectly.